# Finding Property in an Object and returning full path

Tags: node.js

Let me start off with i have searched but could not find an answer specific to what i am looking for. I have Docs which are stored in a NSQL db like mango or couchbase  and those docs have a an object which in turn can hold another object or and array of objects. each opject in the Doc has a unique GUID and i want to be able to find the guid and return the complete path back. I have had success doing so if i hardcore the search path for the guid where to look but i am hoping there is a way to do so without predefined path and sub level limitation.

here is a sample

```
{
"type": "lead",
"id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe10",
"contact": [
{
  "type": "contact",
  "id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe11",
  "dob": "07/12/1978",
  "email": [
    {
      "default": "yes",
      "email_address": "email1@email.com",
      "type": "home",
      "id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe12"
    },
    {
      "default": "no",
      "email_address": "email2@email.com",
      "type": "work",
      "id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe13",
      "note": [
        {
          "id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe73",
          "type": "note",
          "3rdLevel": [
            {
              "id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe77",
              "type": "thirdLevel"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "first_name": "Susi",
  "gender": "f",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "middle_name": "M",
  "suffix": "I",
  "title": ""
},
{
  "type": "contact",
  "id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe10",
  "dob": "07/12/1978",
  "email": [
    {
      "default": "yes",
      "email_address": "email1@email.com",
      "type": "home",
      "id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe22"
    },
    {
      "default": "no",
      "email_address": "email2@email.com",
      "type": "work",
      "id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe23"
    }
  ],
  "first_name": "Susi",
  "gender": "f",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "middle_name": "M",
  "suffix": "I",
  "title": ""
},
{
  "type": "contact",
  "id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe09",
  "dob": "07/12/1978",
  "email": [
    {
      "default": "yes",
      "email_address": "email1@email.com",
      "type": "home",
      "id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe32"
    },
    {
      "default": "no",
      "email_address": "email2@email.com",
      "type": "work",
      "id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe33"
    }
  ],
  "first_name": "Susi",
  "gender": "f",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "middle_name": "M",
  "suffix": "I",
  "title": ""
},
{
  "type": "contact",
  "id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe08",
  "dob": "07/12/1978",
  "email": [
    {
      "default": "yes",
      "email_address": "email1@email.com",
      "type": "home",
      "id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe42"
    },
    {
      "default": "no",
      "email_address": "email2@email.com",
      "type": "work",
      "id": "4416e4cc-89df-4537-b86f-a417614ebe43"
    }
  ],
  "first_name": "Susi",
  "gender": "f",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "middle_name": "M",
  "suffix": "I",
  "title": ""
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase solves nested searches through the "within" keyword (https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html#collection-op-within). You haven't specified the database you are using, so I recommend you to search for a similar operator.

Comment: Thanks but that would require to use N1QL which I don’t plan to use. Since couchbase has the limitation of subdoc operations when it comes to arrays I am getting doc , get the cas and then find path inc index to my object to be able to call update. Still requires 2 calls but there is no other way for now